# Python and Java regex behavior different when using the same regex

Tags: java

There are several questions about this but non answered my question. I wish to use pattern and matcher to find a pattern in a string and then from there create a list out of the matches that include the rest of the not match as well.

```
 String a = "125t160f"; // The "t" could be replaced with symbols such as "." or anything so I wish to take one of anything after many digits.
 Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\.?\\d+\\.)").matcher(a);
 System.out.println(m.find());
```

My current result:

False

My expected result should be in list:

["125t", "160f"] // I understand how to do it in python but not in java. So could anyone assist me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern should be `\d+\D`:

```
String a = "125t160f";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+\\D").matcher(a);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

The above regex pattern says to match one or more digits, followed by a single non digit character.  If we can't rely on a non digit character to know when to stop matching, then we would need to know how many digits to consume.

Comment: Thank you but it didnt give me the rest of the string and not in list form. Is there a way to do so? When I tried re.findall in python, it will return me ["125t", "160t"] the second element is usually the rest of the remaining string.

Comment: and also this pattern will not work if we take chinese character after the digit. For example, "125空". Then it will not take the "空".

Comment: I have answered your question.  If you want to match Chinese numeric characters, then you will have to build your own regex character class for that.

Comment: The one you showed me is to take the same pattern even for the remaining string. It is not taking the whole remaining string. But thank you. For example, "125t126tttttttttt"

Comment: Then use the pattern `\d+\D+`.

Comment: Thank you, I had marked it as answer. if you dont mind, could you tell me why i cant use my current method instead? patter = "[0-9]*[^\\n]?". input= "１２５円３０銭". My output became [１, ２, ５, 円, ３, ０, 銭, ] and not ["125円", "30銭"]

Comment: The logic is off.  The pattern you seem to want is "match some number of digits followed by some number of non digits."  My answer does that, or at least gets you closer to doing that.